# JavaScript/jQuery: Is there any way to use a function on a table only when it is in focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, focus

I'm really new to JavaScript, haven't even finished the track on Codeacademy yet. But I did finish jQuery, HTML/CSS, and Python so the logic at least isn't completely foreign to me...

Anyway, I made a testing page to try to practice my JavaScript skills for the first time, what I ended up doing was making a "color selection" div that will change to different colors when you click on it and then a large table full of different cells that will change to the color of the "color selection" div when the mouse hovers over it. So basically a very simple coloring board. But the way it is, you can't just click on the canvas and start coloring, it'll change colors anytime your mouse enters that part of the screen whether you selected it or not.

The "canvas" itself is just a large table. And if I'm understanding correctly, I can't just use .focus() on a table.

So I guess to put it simply... what I'm wondering is if there is any way to say "when this table is in focus, do X when the mouse hovers over (this)". 
Or else, "when the user clicks in this table, make these cells change color when the mouse hovers. But when the user clicks outside of the table, stop doing that."

Is this even a possibility or did I go about this all in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tJr6J/)

```
$('#myelem').attr('tabindex',-1).hover(function () {
    if (document.activeElement === this) {
        console.log('hover');
    }
});
```

Setting tabindex attribute is for crossbrowser support of focus event as in some browser, by default without setting tabindex, some html element don't natively support focus.

BTW, if you don't want focused element to be restyled by browser, you could add this css to the elements:

```
$('#myelem').css('outline',0).attr('tabindex',-1).hover(function () {...});
```